# Structure of finitely generated modules over local Artinian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $(R,m)$ be an Artinian local ring with $m^2=0$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$ module. Can we say anything about the structure of $M$? Perhaps to give a complete structure might be very difficult, but can we say anything "nice"?

Comment: Good question. At least when $R$ is a principal ideal ring, which happens to be the case in the "typical" case $R=k[x]/(x^2)$, it is clear what to do.

Comment: @Martin The answer below is really great, bravo!!!!!

Answer (score 13):

More generally let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring with a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ satisfying $\mathfrak{m}^2=0$. Then every finitely generated $R$-module $M$ fits into a canonical exact sequence of finitely generated $R$-modules
$$0 \to \mathfrak{m} M \to M \to M/\mathfrak{m} M \to 0.$$
Since $\mathfrak{m} M$ and $M/\mathfrak{m} M$ are killed by $\mathfrak{m}$ (here we use $\mathfrak{m}^2=0$), these correspond to $R/\mathfrak{m}$-modules. Thus, there are unique natural numbers $r,s \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\mathfrak{m} M \cong (R/\mathfrak{m})^s, \quad M/\mathfrak{m} M \cong (R/\mathfrak{m})^r.$$
Thus, $M$ is determined by these two natural numbers and the extension class
$$[M] \in \mathrm{Ext}^1_R\bigl((R/\mathfrak{m})^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s\bigr).$$
So we have to determine $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R((R/\mathfrak{m})^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s)$. In principle, because $\mathrm{Ext}$ is additive in both variables, we may restrict to $r=s=1$ here, but later I would like to describe the extensions explicitly for general $r,s$. And it's not harder at all to do the general case right away.

The long exact sequence associated to the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathfrak{m}^r \to R^r \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^r \to 0$ begins with:
$$0 \to \mathrm{Hom}_R((R/\mathfrak{m})^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s) \to \mathrm{Hom}_R(R^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s) \to \mathrm{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{m}^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s) \cdots \\ \to \mathrm{Ext}^1_R\bigl((R/\mathfrak{m})^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s\bigr) \to \mathrm{Ext}^1_R\bigl(R^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s\bigr)$$
Since $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R(R^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s)=0$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_R((R/\mathfrak{m})^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s) \to \mathrm{Hom}_R(R^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s)$ is an isomorphism, the sequence simplifies to
$$\mathrm{Ext}^1_R\bigl((R/\mathfrak{m})^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s\bigr) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{m}^r,(R/\mathfrak{m})^s).$$
Given a homomorphism $\delta : \mathfrak{m}^r \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^s$, the corresponding extension
$$0 \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^s \to E_\delta \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^r \to 0$$
is constructed as follows (see Weibel's *Introduction to homological algebra*, proof of Thm 3.4.3): We define $E_\delta$ as a pushout:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathfrak{m}^r @>{\subseteq}>>  R^r \\ @V{\delta}VV @VVV \\ (R/\mathfrak{m})^s  @>>> E_\delta \end{CD}$$
Explicitly, we have
$$E_\delta = (R^r \oplus (R/\mathfrak{m})^s) / \bigl\{(x,-\delta(x)) : x \in \mathfrak{m}^r\bigr\}.$$
The homomorphism $E_\delta \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^r$ is induced by $0 : (R/\mathfrak{m})^s \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^r$ and the projection $R^r \twoheadrightarrow (R/\mathfrak{m})^r$.

Therefore, every finitely generated $R$-module is isomorphic to $E_\delta$ for unique natural numbers $r,s$ and a unique homomorphism $\delta : \mathfrak{m}^r \to (R/\mathfrak{m})^s$. This finishes the classification.

Comment: This is a nice answer, somehow you used the hypothesis $m^2=0$. I would have upvoted it even more, but i can do it only once, i think. The other answer is nice too but i knew that, it appears as one of the steps in proving matlis duality.

Comment: There is something wrong with your answer, already in the simplest case $R=\mathbb Z_4$ and ${\frak m}=(2) \triangleleft R$. Every f.g. $R$-module $M$ is a direct sum of cyclic modules (see below), and the only cyclic $R$-modules are $R=\mathbb Z_4$ itself and $R/{\frak m}=\mathbb Z_2$. If $M= \oplus_p \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \oplus_q \mathbb Z_2$ then $M/2M=\oplus_{p+q}\mathbb Z_2$ and $2M=\oplus_p\mathbb Z_2$, so $s \leq r$ is essential. (Posted by @AndrewRanicki as an answer.)

Comment: Where is my mistake exactly?

Comment: Oh no, could not find the error.

Answer (score 7):

One case is really nice, and the other case is not so nice.

### When $m$ is principal:

You can show that in fact $R$ has exactly three ideals $\{R,m,\{0\}\}$, and so it's an [Artinian uniserial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniserial_ring#Properties_of_uniserial_and_serial_rings_and_modules) (a.k.a. an Artinian local, principal ideal ring or "[special principal ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring#Structure_theory_for_commutative_PIR.27s)").  It's known that *every* module (f.g. or not) over an Artinian uniserial ring is a direct sum of cyclic submodules. That's pretty nice, IMHO.

### When $m$ isn't principal:

At the very least you have that (for finitely generated $M$) $M$ has finite composition length (and is therefore Artinian and Noetherian,) and, that the socle $\operatorname{Soc}(M)$ is essential in $M$. Thus $M$ has to be a submodule $\operatorname{Soc}(M)\subseteq M\subseteq E(\operatorname{Soc}(M))$ where $E(-)$ denotes the injective hull.

What does the localness of $R$ buy us? Two things: one is that there is exactly one isotype of simple $R$ module, namely $R/m=S$. Secondly, since $R$ is Artinian, $R/m$ embeds in $R$ as an $R$ module, so it is actually a copy of an ideal of $R$. This means that $\operatorname{Soc}(M)\cong \oplus_{i=1}^nS$, and consequently $M\subseteq E(\operatorname{Soc}(M))\cong\oplus_{i=1}^nE(S)$.

Since $E(S)$ is a indecomposable, we can say that $M$ is an essential submodule of a finite direct sum of copies of an indecomposible injective module.

Comment: Sorry, why does $R/m$ embed into $R$?

Comment: @rschwieb I do agree that your answer is indeed nice. But may i wait for one day before i accept your answer in case somebody comes up with a nicer answer which somehow uses that $m^2=0$ to make it "more" nicer. I have one silly question, so pardon me. $R/m$ embeds in $R$, why?

Comment: (Note: If it wasn't clear before, I should emphasize that it is an embedding of modules, not rings, of course.) Elementary: since $R$ is Artinian, it has a simple submodule $A$. Since $R$ is local, it has exactly one isotype of simple modules, namely $R/m$. Therefore $R/m\cong A$. Rings with this embedding property are called [Kasch rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasch_ring).

Comment: @user114539 Sounds OK: I can't think of a way to exploit the square zero radical, at the moment. I'll let you know if something comes to mind, though :)

Comment: @rschwieb: One has the obvious consequence that E(S) (like all modules over R/m^2) has a filtration 0 ≤ N ≤ E(S) with N and E(S)/N isomorphic to direct sums of copies of S. N=S in this case, but E(S)/N need not be simple, rather E(S)/N has the same composition length as m does.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks: I thought of the filtration, but since I'm mostly ignorant about what filtrations say, I couldn't do anything with it :) Is there in fact more to say about $M$ with the filtration?

Comment: Nothing more exciting. M too has a submodule S^n with quotient S^m. Nothing about the extension, other than being nonsplit.

Comment: A MathOverflow reference for "It's known that every module (f.g. or not) over an Artinian uniserial ring is a direct sum of cyclic submodules" : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22722/why-are-finitely-generated-modules-over-principal-artin-local-rings-direct-sums (Posted as an answer by @AndrewRanicki)