# The structure of the quotients of free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, quotient-spaces, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative (unitary) ring. Every $R$-module is the quotient of a free $R$-module, and every free $R$-module with basis $B$ is isomorphic to $R^{\oplus B}:=\bigoplus_{i\in B}R$. That is, every $R$-module can be written as a quotient

$$R^{\oplus I}/N,$$

where $I$ is some index set and $N$ is a submodule of $R^{\oplus I}$. I'm looking for ways to categorize these quotient modules in order to categorize all $R$-modules. One that comes to mind immediately is the fundamental theorem on finitely generated modules over principal ideal domains: Every finitely generated module over a principal ideal domain $R$ is of the form

$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n R/(a_i),$$

where $a_i\in R$ and $a_i\vert a_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$. This also means that for PIDs, $R^n/N\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n Q_i$, where $Q_i$ are quotients of $R$, which is the kind of thing I'm looking for. Though this is a non-trivial theorem and it requires strong conditions: a finite generating set and we need a PID. Are there more elementary results about the structure of quotients of free modules?

Edit: To clarify, I'm not looking for a complete classification of all possible modules. Partial results, for instance ones holding only over certain kinds of rings, are also fine. Im mostly looking for really broad categories of modules, not the kind of complete categorization we have for vector spaces.

Comment: While this is a highly interesting question, I expect that seeking a classification of $R$-modules in general is a very ambiguous goal, and your question might be too broad to elicit a satisfying response. However, I know that there are some very experienced experts active here and I hope that one of them will be able to give a good (summary) response.

Comment: This is extremely broad, because you seem to really be talking about all $R$-modules. Nevertheless, a fruitful direction to go in is to examine properties of free (or projective) resolutions. As an example of something related to this philosophy: a local Noetherian ring $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ is regular if and only if any finitely generated $R$-module has a finite free resolution.

Comment: As noted above, the question is too broad, as it is equivalent to asking for a classification of all modules over any commutative ring $R$.  This is deemed a hopeless task in general; algebras and rings for which such a classification is possible are usually called *tame*, and the others are *wild* (wild algebras being defined in a more complex manner than just being "not tame", but this is another matter).

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon: Yes, the question is very broad, but I'm not asking for a complete classification of all modules. I'm also interested in partial results, which may also be very broad. Something like: over such and such rings, modules are direct sums of quotients of the ring itself. Such results would seem pretty nice, but would still leave the task of actually finding the quotients of said ring.

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in the classification of finitely generated modules over Dedekind domains. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain.

Comment: @QiZhu: Thus is nice! Thanks!

Comment: This is also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623261.